# Presto "Failed to list directory" when connecting to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, presto

In Presto, I tried to connect hive by configuring hive connectors as mentioned in https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#configuration

It works fine when I use `Show Tables` command.

But When I used to fetch the data from table using select query `SELECT * FROM sample_table`. I got this below error

> Failed to list directory:
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/sample.db/sample_table

Could you please guide me what mistake I had done here.

**Note:** Hive is running in one machine and Presto is in another machine.

Comment: This means you have access to Metastore, but not to HDFS name node. Is the name node running on `localhost`?